# Ordering 2 symmetric matrices in the same fashion

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, dataframe

I have 2 symmetric matrices, one of them being a correlation matrix and the other one similar to a correlation matrix. Examples of these matrices are shown below:

**Correlation Matrix (c):**

```
    A    B    C    D
A   1   0.5  0.1  0.4
B   0.5   1   0.9  0.3
C   0.1  0.9   1   0.3
D   0.4  0.3  0.3   1
```

**Other Matrix (z):**

```
    A    B    C    D
A   3    2    2    2
B   2    3    3    2
C   2    3    3    2
D   2    2    2    3
```

I'm ordering the correlation matrix in descending order so I can look at the top-most correlation values, using the following code:

```
c = corrMatrixMin10.abs()
s = c.unstack()
so = s.sort_values(kind="quicksort")
pd.DataFrame(so[so.values!=1].sort_values(ascending=False))
```

My question is as follows:

When I arrange the correlation matrix `c` in a descending order, the correlation matrix itself loses its shape. How do I have the other matrix `z` in the exact same order?

For example: The intersection of columns `A` and `B` in the matrix `c` is `0.5`. The intersection of columns `A` and `B` in the matrix `z` is `2`. How can I still preserve this order to associate these 2 values after arranging the matrix `c` in a descending order?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA.

The code to generate the 2 matrices is as follows:

```
c = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0.5,  0.1, 0.4],
                   [0.5,  1,  0.9, 0.3],
                   [ 0.1,  0.9,  1, 0.3],
                   [ 0.4, 0.3, 0.3,  1]],
                  columns=list('ABCD'))

z = pd.DataFrame([[3, 2,  2, 2],
                   [2,  3,  3, 2],
                   [ 2,  3,  3, 2],
                   [ 2, 2, 2,  3]],
                  columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html)

```
c_series = c.unstack().drop([(x, x) for x in c]).sort_values(ascending=False)
z_series = z.unstack().reindex(c_series.index)
```